# Best way to send a message to multiple children view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter, childviewcontroller

I implemented a custom `UIViewController` which has multiple child view controllers (mainly by using the storyboard's `Container View` but not only).

I'm wondering what is the best way for the "root" view controller to send a message to its children, taking into account that the child(s) view controller(s) concerned by the message sent is not necessarily a direct child of the "root" view controller ?

For example:

[image: View controllers hierarchy]

I want to send a message from `#0` to view controllers `#1` and `#4`. The naïve implementation is to iterate over the child of `#0` and send them the message, like so:

```
for (UIViewController *childVC in self.childViewControllers)
{
    if ([childVC respondsToSelector:@selector(myMessage:)])
    {
        [childVC performSelector@selector(myMessage:)];
    }
}
```

But it simply doesn't work, because `#3` will receive the message (or probably not if it is a `UINavigationController` and I'm calling a custom method) and don't propagate it to its children (here `#4`).

So **is there a possibility to send a message to one's children, and let the message propagate through the `UIViewController` hierarchy ?**

If not, an alternative would be to use the `NSNotificationCenter`, make the children interested in the message (`#1` and `#4`) observe for a notification, and make the root view controller post a notification when necessary. But I find it a bit of an overkill only to dispatch a message to two children.

Comment: In first place, if the method takes an argument, and you invoke it without one, that's UB.

Comment: I don't think it's overkill - use NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: Classic NSNotificationCenter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to avoid `NSNotificationCenter`, because if one is not careful it will create a bit of [Spaghetti Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). Still, **in this case I would use it**, because it's even more of a overkill to taking of the logic of how the message should propagate between the childsViewControllers and possibility the ochildsViewControllers's childs.

Comment: Notification center it is then. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think going through `NSNotificationCenter` is the best way to go. Each child view controller can decide for themselves what notifications they want to respond to; it takes the responsibility of filtering away from the object posting the notification.

- [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [And its Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this, but I'm not saying its a good idea:

```
@interface UIViewController (ReverseResponder)

- (void)reverseRespond:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)object;

@end

@implementation UIViewController (ReverseResponder)

- (void)reverseRespond:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)object
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        [self performSelector:selector withObject:object];
    }

    for (UIViewController* childViewController in self.childViewControllers) {
        [childViewController reverseRespond:selector withObject:object];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all of your children with self.childViewControllers, and pass a specific index to get to a particular child. To get to 4, you'll have to access 3's topViewController.

```
UIViewController *child4 = [(UINavigationController *)self.childViewControllers[2] topViewController];
```

Whether this is a good way to do this, depends on what you're trying to do. Why are you sending messages down to this level?